# Gitlab CI not caching

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-8

I have the following gitlab ci yaml file:

```
image: steveedson/ci

stages:
  - build

cache:
  untracked: true
  key: "$CI_PROJECT_ID"
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - _site/vendor/
    - .bundled/
    - .yarn

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ls -l
    - yarn config set cache-folder .yarn
    - yarn install
    - ...
```

When my successful builds finish, they show:

```
Creating cache 1970478...
Created cache
```

And when the next commit triggers a build, I get:

```
Checking cache for 1970478...
Successfully extracted cache
```

But the `ls -l` in my first step doesn't show the cached directories. I've tried caching the cache key but this doesn't help.

This is running on gitlab.com, not a private server.

Comment: Note: Shared runners in Gitlab doesn't support cache between jobs/pipelines.

Answer (score 6):

So, my configuration is correct, and Gitlab does support caches between jobs, however they have not added this to shared runners on gitlab.com, yet.

The issue is here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/infrastructure/issues/919 and should be added soon.

Comment: It's not for me either but I'm using a specific runner not a shared one :/

Comment: On Gitlab.com, or a private instance?

Comment: Privately. It came out that the Runner 9.0 has a bug. 9.0.1 fixes it. Generally handling caches in docker executor failed. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/2276#note_26425178

Answer (score 0):

Caching doesn't seem to work if you run your config locally with something like:
`sudo gitlab-runner exec docker tests --docker-image "image/image"`

Once I tested this through my Gitlab instance caching was working.